# "is not a function" error when another unrelated function is in the code

Tags: javascript, this, anonymous-function

I have two pieces of code that each work as expected:

```js
function Test() {}

let tmp = function() {
    console.log(this)
}
tmp.call(Test)
```

and

```js
function Test() {}

(function() {
    console.log(this)
}).call(Test)
```

They both produce the expected output: `[Function: Test]`.

However, when these *independent* code fragments are combined, it produces an error. So, running the following code

```js
function Test() {}

let tmp = function() {
    console.log(this)
}
tmp.call(Test)

(function() {
    console.log(this)
}).call(Test)
```

results in

```
TypeError: tmp.call(...) is not a function
```

I found a non-elegant fix for this, which is adding a delay to the second code fragment. So, the following would produce the desired output (`[Function: Test]` twice):

```js
function Test() {}

let tmp = function() {
    console.log(this)
}
tmp.call(Test)

setTimeout(() => {
    (function() {
        console.log(this)
    }).call(Test)
}, 100);
```

The fact that the timeout seems to fix it makes me think it's related to some asynchronous stuff, but I can't explain *exactly* why it's happening.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're falling victim to an automatic semicolon insertion trap. The code

```
tmp.call(Test)

(function() {
    console.log(this)
}).call(Test)
```

is interpreted as if it were written

```
tmp.call(Test)(function() { console.log(this) }).call(Test)
```

If a semicolon is introduced:

```
tmp.call(Test);

(function() {
    console.log(this)
}).call(Test)
```

then it will work.

The precise rules involve some "legalese" that's somewhat hard to digest, but the basic idea (in this case) is that a semicolon won't be inserted when an expression can syntactically work when the newline is considered to be a simple space character.

Comment: Yeah, putting a semicolon fixes it

Comment: I'll never understand why people want to get rid of semicolons;

Comment: @zero298 Some JS code formatting standards clearly state that semicolons are not required and must be omitted. For example, https://standardjs.com/rules.html#semicolons.

Comment: @zero298 because some people keep switching between languages that do and don't use them, and JS doesn't even warn about the lack of semicolons.

Comment: I've got C, C++, and Java so firmly wired into my head that missing `;` code makes me uncomfortable, but I'm happy for everyone to follow their heart in the matter. (Learning Erlang was really trippy.)

Answer (score 2):

This is how your code snippet is interpreted:

```
function Test() {}

let tmp = function() {
    console.log(this)
}
tmp.call(Test)(function() {
    console.log(this)
}).call(Test)
```

To fix it, add a semi-colon after `tmp.call(Test)`